# How to enable my own documentation in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, documentation, xcode13

I am developing in Swift an iOS App and want to write my documentation about code and concepts within Xcode using the Documentation catalog feature.

I created a documentation catalog within my Swift-project. I created two files named `Documentation.md` and `Features.md` in the catalog-folder.

In Build Settings under "Documentation Compiler - Options" I set "Build Documentation during Build" to `Yes`.

I run `Product -> Build Documentation` and Apple`s Documentation Window opens and presents a lot of documentation but nothing from me. What do I need to change?

Comment: Are you talking about the new DocC documentation system? DocC does not currently support apps. It only supports Swift packages and frameworks.

Comment: How do I build a documentation of my iOS App?

Comment: Can you generate documentation for your app with Xcode 13.3? Xcode 13.3 adds DocC support for apps.